# JavaScript insertAdjacentHTML overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an inbox system that updates as the user receives or sends messages. Whenever I send the second message, they overlap. I'm trying to figure out how to lay them out in rows, similar to an email system. I'm not 100% sure if I've got to rework my HTMl to use a grid.

```
const btnComposeMessageSend = document.querySelector(".compose-message-send");
const inboxRow = document.querySelector(".inbox-row");

const updateInbox = function() {
  const html = ` <div class="inbox-line">
    <p class="inbox-row-date">02/03/23</p>
    <p class="inbox-row-sender">Greg Piercer</p>
    <p class="inbox-row-message">Hello There</p>
</div>
  `;
  inboxRow.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html);
};

btnComposeMessageSend.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  updateInbox();
});
.inbox-line {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}

.inbox-row-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.inbox-row-sender {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 80px;
  width: 150px;
}

.inbox-row-message {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}
<div class="inbox-row">
  <div class="inbox-line">
    <p class="inbox-row-date"></p>
    <p class="inbox-row-sender"></p>
    <p class="inbox-row-message"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="compose-message-send">Send</button>
```

This is the HTML attached.

Comment: If `inboxRow` refers to `<div class="inbox-row">` you're putting the new row inside an existing row. You probably want `beforebegin` to create a new row

Comment: I changed it up, the devtool shows that the Lines are being made individually of each other, however, they still overlap, might have to look at CSS and maybe rework HTMl - thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: If you need more help, post a [mre]

Comment: I'll give it another look over and if I'm still stumped I'll edit the post, thank you again

Comment: Thought I'd update you a bit, put the code in a separate file, used a grid and it's working all fine now, just ironing out creases